# How to see table according to another table's ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server

See table according to another tables ID.
Example: see what countries from country table an id = 5 from users table has visited.

I think it needs a subquery for this task.

```
Select * from country where (select id from users where id = 5)
```

It doesn't work correctly.

**Edit**

user table

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(6)  NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30)  NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
  ('1', 'jackie'),
  ('2', 'maria'),
  ('3', 'sandra')
```

country table

```
CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `name` varchar(30)  NOT NULL,
  `capital` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
) ;
INSERT INTO `country` (`name`, `capital`) VALUES
  ('Italy', 'Rome'),
  ('Portugal', 'Lisbon'),
  ('China', 'Beijing'),
  ('Norway', 'Oslo');
```

**Purpose**: users can mark the countries visited so the program should have the ability to show which countries a user has visited.

Hence we want a query that shows the info for each country a user with id = 5 has visited.

Example user = 5 has visited Italy and Norway.

**UPDATE** NEW

to add countries a user has visited:

```
CREATE TABLE `country_visited`(
    `userId` INT(6) not null,
    `country` varchar(30) not null
);
INSERT INTO `country_visited` (`userid`,`country`) VALUES
  ('1', 'Spain'),
  ('2', 'Norway'),
  ('3', 'Italy'),
  ('4', 'Spain'),
  ('5', 'Italy'); #if this has visited 3 countries how do you add it?
```

Comment: How do you know user = 5 has visited Italy and Norway.

Comment: You have tagged the question "sql-server", but the syntax is MySQL.

Comment: The point is to make the database structure that way so the query in question can return tht information.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes because I want to make it to work in SQLSERVER but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

You first need a table to store which countries a user had visited. For example

```
CREATE TABLE countryVisited(
    userId INT not null
    country varchar(30) not null
)
```

Insert into the table:

```
INSERT INTO countryVisited (userId,country) VALUES
  (5, 'Norway'),
  (4, 'Spain'),
  (5, 'Italy')
```

You can then join as follows:

```
SELECT id, name, c.country, capital
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN countryVisited cv
    ON u.id = cv. userId
INNER JOIN country c
    ON cv.country = c.country
WHERE u.id=5
```

Even better, add an id field to the `country` table and only store that value in the `countryVisited` table instead of the country name.

Comment: Why would you set country to varchar(50), when the original country column only has varchar(30)? Also, there is no FOREIGN KEY in your create.

Comment: Looks very good but what if the user has visited more than one country? How it would pass more than one?

Comment: You add a row to the table for each country the user visited. The query will then return all the countries the user visited.

Comment: @elizabk Check the last update to see what I am saying.Thanks

Comment: Can you suggest changes so it runs in SQLserver?

Comment: Edited to show insert of one user visiting multiple countries

Answer (score 0):

You should have another table which stores the relation between `User` and `Country`. Something like this:

```
UserCountries Table

 UserID       CountryId
-------     -------------
   1              1
   1              2
   2              1
   2              3
```

Then you should write a query like this:

```
Select * from Country where Id in
(select CountryId from UserCountries
 where UserId = 5)
```

Comment: Check the updated version to see why this is not working

Answer (score 0):

After edit your question I can understand the matter. Now you can use the structure   for solved your problem.

Edit your user table as like as user_id, user_name, visited_country_id.

when a user choose his visited country then update user table visited_country_id using comma separator. For an Example

user_id   user_name      visited_country_id
5          Selim           1,3,4

Now you execute query like  select* from country where country_id in (select visited_country_id from user where user_id=5)